# Incremental Saving

Tags: ios, save

I have an app with a lot of data (including NSMutableArrays, NSNumbers, various custom classes) that uses NSCoding protocol presently.  However, I would like to implement an incremental saving system, to save time during the "saving process".  The loading time is not important.

Is there any existing container that checks its members for "dirty" and only updates those values when writing to file; or better yet, a protocol that can be implemented to do the same; or any other simple, available way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For large amount of data its better to change data model to Core Data. Otherwise, you may want to save changes after specific events, or, bad solution is to use NSTimer, to save all data every time you want to.

Comment: The second statement is correct: I want to save the changes on app entering background or terminating but it is too much to save all at once; My question is about the implementation of "saving changes".

Comment: Specify events when information should be saved (pressing "done" button, tapping row, entering background. etc.). Maybe you should make BOOL flags to determine if you need to save specific data or not, to minimize effort, and save only data that is changed.